# CentOS 6.6 TCadmin - Server not responding to query

Tags: linux, centos, hosting, dedicated-server

Hello "stackers" i've been trying the past few days to set-up TCadmin GamePanel on my CentOS server.

We're running CentOS 64 bit, with 32 lib installed.

-We can create Murmur/counter-strike: Source servers running without problems.

-Other servers not responding to query.

-we've allowed port range 27015 - 27030

-SteamCMD is running and we can connect to steam API (tried via. the server)

Following folder names are with lowercases:

```
/home/tcagame/user
/home/tcadmin/tcafiles/games
/home/tcadmin/tcafiles/users
```

So after what my research lead to. It isn't because of uppercase letters.

We've tried to reinstall the entire server but nothing works.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

(if some info are missing i'll provide them to you)

Best regards

Rune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

TCadmin support responded to our ticket:

Bu default Tcadmin Runs the "srcds.exe"

This is not the right file to run

Cilck on the server, choose  service settings and change "srcds.exe" to "srcds_run"